# Fail to get top left coordinates of span element inside phantomjs, but in browser it works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, phantomjs

I have simple phantomjs script which gives incorrect results for top left coordinates of one of the spans on the page. At first I thought this is because span is inline element, but I do know that jQuery is able to get correct coordinates while browsing page live, yet it fails when running from phantomjs. Is it phantomjs problem? Is it possible to workaround?

Here is the script

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
    page.viewportSize = { width: 1200, height: 800 };

    page.open('http://metalnoir.com/process/', function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            phantom.exit();
        }
        page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) { console.log(msg); };

        page.evaluate(function() {
//this one works
            var jhdr = jQuery('body>div#main-container>div#content-container>div#full-width>div#portfolio-preview-container>div:nth-of-type(2)>div#portfolio-wrapper>div:nth-of-type(1)>div:nth-of-type(4)>h6');
            var hdr = jhdr.get(0);
            console.log(hdr.outerHTML);
            console.log(jhdr.offset().top + ' ' + jhdr.offset().left + ' ' + jhdr.width() + ' ' + jhdr.height());
            var hdrrect = hdr.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log(hdrrect.top + ' ' + hdrrect.left + ' ' + hdrrect.bottom + ' ' + hdrrect.right);
//this one doesn't
            var jspn = jQuery('body>div#main-container>div#content-container>div#full-width>div#portfolio-preview-container>div:nth-of-type(2)>div#portfolio-wrapper>div:nth-of-type(1)>div:nth-of-type(4)>span');
            var spn = jspn.get(0);
            console.log(spn.outerHTML);
            console.log(jspn.offset().top + ' ' + jspn.offset().left + ' ' + jspn.width() + ' ' + jspn.height());
            var spnrect = spn.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log(spnrect.top + ' ' + spnrect.left + ' ' + spnrect.bottom + ' ' + spnrect.right);
        });                                     
        phantom.exit();
    });
```

Here is the sample script output

```
<h6>Polishing</h6> off 85 10
461.59375 215.59375 121 21
461.59375 215.59375 482.59375 336.296875
<span class="post-info">Process</span> off 0 0
0 0 50 0
0 0 0 0
```

While h6 is ok with coordinates (just to illustrate script works), span has zeroes. In browser, span has something like 377, 345, 121, 17 (depends on view size, of course). But certainly not zeroes.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Have you looked into the screenshot whether *this* span is shown? Have you tried to increase the viewport size to something desktop-like to see if it reappears?

Comment: I have. And it is not shown. I am just trying to understand why. Also, just increased view port size to 1600 with same results.

Comment: Well, I have saved file locally, and start testing it by stripping links to css files. And at some point span became visible. I will research the problem and post the reason/solution (if find one). Thanks for worries, anyway. As often happens, when you explained the problem to someone, you have partly solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
In short, it looks like that malformed css is interpreted by browser and phantomjs differently. While browser (I've tried Chrome and IE) stops css processing at malformed style, phantomjs continues.

Now details:

I saved file locally and started removing links to css files one by one. After removal of one css file span suddenly appeared. File had malformed media directive

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:800px {
#logo-container a img {max-height:52px !important;}
}
```

After that it has rule which hides span in question

```
.post-info {
display: none !important;
}
```

So, I assume that browser stops after malformed rule and phantomjs continues and applies "none" rule. That's why I did not see span on phantomjs rendered screenshot and was unable to get correct coordinates.

After that, the workaround was simple -override display style

```
if (jspn.hasClass('post-info')) jspn.attr('style', 'display: inline !important;');
```

Final output

```
<h6>Polishing</h6> off 85 10
461.59375 415.59375 121 21
461.59375 415.59375 482.59375 536.296875
<span class="post-info" style="display: inline !important;">Process</span> off 85 31
482.59375 415.59375 121 17
482.59375 415.59375 499.59375 536.296875
```